# Angular number pipe for large number unspected display (E+45)

Tags: angular

I have this casuistry...

Input:
`{{ (5555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555 | number : '1.2-2') }}`

**Expected**: 555,555,555,555,555,555,555,555,555,555,555,555,555,555,555,5.00 or 5555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555.00

**Displayed**: 5.56E+45

Is there a way to get the expected behavior with a build angular pipe?

Comment: Can you provide an example ? I can't reproruce the behavior you describe

Comment: Im testing on chrome in a windows 10 PC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't an Angular issue. Support for large integers is not a native feature of JavaScript.

```
console.log(5555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555); // prints 5.555555555555555e+45
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER); // prints 9007199254740991
```

There is a specification for a future version of JavaScript that will support a `BigInt` number type.

There is a *polyfill* that you can add that will enable `BigInt` support in today's browsers.

https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js

This will let you do the following

```
const largeNumber = bigInt("5555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555");
console.log(largeNumber.toString());
```

You will have to write your own *pipe* to format the number, and I think the above library has some formatting features.